# How to find that are there any duplicates AND already checked?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I would like to know if there is a duplicate value in my sheet and if it as been already checked.

Example:

```
Error     ID
          001
1         002
1         001
          003
          002
```

In this example, I'd like the last row to contains the number 0 in the Error column to know that it has been checked and I just need to do half of the task to write the number 1.

I already know how to find duplicates:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, $B$2)>1
```

But I want to check also if the value in the Error column is 1 (I think I need to use "AND" somewhere...).
I also tried with COUNTIFS formula but it returns to many results (it's more like a "OR" than a "AND").

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you try to use VBA ?

Comment: @matzone I think it is possible to do it without VBA so I'd like to find the right formula...

Comment: what if there is a duplicate in your sheet and it isn't checked? What do you want to return? You could try      =AND(A2=1,COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1)  or      =AND(A2=0,COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1)

Answer (score -1):

It is not really clear what your goal is, [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!1cRASbJD!aFUeeTsHQWg1SxQ7H4pjVUrBC_hMixLVE8i7XSL7o_Y) are some examples that might help.